# Checking property of images crashing in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

I used this function to scan all photos from the Camera Album in iPhone/ iPad. I don't know why, for me it was crashing all the time. I really don't have any idea about where it is crashing in this function, . Sometimes it worked fine, when I changed iCloud Photo Stream to ON/OFF in Settings in iPhone/IPad. I have no idea why this happens.

This is the function which I wrote. I am passing array of PHAssets into this function.

```
 func gettingSize(from array : NSMutableArray)
    {
        func enumerateAllImages(imageArray : NSMutableArray, completion : ((ArrayPassed : NSMutableArray) -> Void)?)
        {

            // Performing progressView addition

            var TempArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

            var options : PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.synchronous = true
            options.networkAccessAllowed = false // to skip download image from iCloud

            let imageManager : PHImageManager = PHImageManager()

            for index in 0...(imageArray.count - 1)
            {
                var ID = imageManager.requestImageDataForAsset( imageArray[index] as PHAsset, options: options, resultHandler:
                    {
                        data,stringValue,orientation,object in

                        var value : NSString = stringValue

                        if (value as NSString).containsString(".png")
                        {
                            if let isIniCloud = object as NSDictionary?
                            {
                                var isIniCloudDICT : NSDictionary = isIniCloud

                                if let integerCloudValue = isIniCloudDICT.valueForKeyPath(PHImageResultIsInCloudKey) as? Int
                                {

                                    if integerCloudValue == 0
                                    {
                                        if index == (imageArray.count - 1)
                                        {
                                            self.tempImageSize = self.tempImageSize + data.length
                                            TempArray.addObject(imageArray[index])
                                            self.increasingTheValue()
                                            completion!(ArrayPassed: TempArray)
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            self.tempImageSize = self.tempImageSize + data.length
                                            TempArray.addObject(imageArray[index])
                                        }

                                    } // Checking condition for integerValueCloud
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if index == (imageArray.count - 1)
                                        {
                                            completion!(ArrayPassed: TempArray)
                                        }
                                    }

                                } // Is in iCloud Optional checking
                                else
                                {
                                    if index == (imageArray.count - 1)
                                    {
                                        completion!(ArrayPassed: TempArray)
                                    }
                                }

                            } // Is in iCloud NSDictionary optional checking
                            else
                            {
                                if index == (imageArray.count - 1)
                                {
                                    completion!(ArrayPassed: TempArray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if index == (imageArray.count - 1)
                            {
                                completion!(ArrayPassed: TempArray)
                            }
                        }
                }) // Image Manager
            } // For loop
        } // Nested Function

        enumerateAllImages( array, { ArrayPassed in

            if ArrayPassed.count == 0
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.progressView.progress = 0
                    self.tempProgress = 0
                    self.increasingTheValue()
                })
            }
            else
            {
                self.Array = ArrayPassed
            }
        })
    }
```

Does anybody knows why this happens, when I run it, it crashes? Crahes on  this line

```
 var value : NSString = stringValue
```

Multiple times, no idea why this happens.?

Comment: Where does the code crash and what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @Thomas The code crash on  if condition checking the MIME type. There is no name for the error type. Sometimes it works by ON/OFF iCloud Photo Stream in settings.

Comment: @Thomas Please take a look, question modified

Comment: Looks like stringValue is either nil or not NSString. What does the error message say?

Comment: Yeah, I'd have to agree with Thomas – it's likely that `stringValue` is nil. Putting it into a non-optional `value` variable of type `NSString` would crash the app in this case. I've not used that class, but it sounds like a likely case.

Comment: @AshFurrow   imageManager.requestImageDataForAsset(<#asset: PHAsset!#>, options: <#PHImageRequestOptions!#>, resultHandler: <#((NSData!, String!, UIImageOrientation, [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!##(NSData!, String!, UIImageOrientation, [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void#>)  . From this method we can see that, every values comes as non nil (! associated with each value). Then why should i check for nil values in these parameters, Curious.?